# VSTS dotnet restore corporate (or self-signed) certificate issue

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I am trying the `dotnet restore` command on the build step process. My nuget store is in Artifactory. Despite installing the corporate certificate, i am getting a SSL issue. My VSTS agent is running in a Ubuntu container on kubernetes

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://<artifactory url>/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Client.HostingStartup'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
   The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Do we need to do any addition steps for the VSTS agent to pick up self-signed certificates?

Comment: Hi @palle Did you check out below workarounds? How was it going? Please let me know if there is any question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working by installing the corporate certificate in the ubuntu container which hosts your VSTS agent. You can try below workarounds:

1, Create a Nuget [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to authenticate Artifactory nuget server.

You can create the service connection by adding a new `Credentials for feeds ...` in the **dotnet restore task**. See below: Click `+ New`

[image]

Then enter your credentials for Artifactory server. See below screeshot.

[image]

2. Another possible workaround is creating a **Artifactory Service Connection** and use **Artifactory Nuget** task  to restore your packages. See [Artifactory Azure DevOps Extension](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-TriggeringNugetBuilds) for more information.

Install [JFrog Artifactory](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) extension to your azure devops organziation. Then add Artifactory Nuget Task in your pipeline to restore your package.

Click `+ New` from **Artifactory Nuget task** to add an Artifactory service connection.

[image]